# how do I stop Windows XP from switching to ActiveDesktop?

Tags: windows-xp, windows-explorer

I usually keep my background a plain black solid color,however from time to time windows will display the message saying "active desktop recovery" on a white background.
this is very annoying and despite being able to successfully fix the issue, it comes back after a couple restarts. is there a way to completely disable this?
(system Windows XP SP3)

Comment: +1 because I am very curious. I had this in the past and the only solution I found was a windows reinstallation. (Turning it of would not work, it would complain about some script errors).